# Is there a way to search for words and phrases in English-language translations of Nietzsche's works?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche

Are you aware of a way to search English-language translations of Nietzsche's works? It would be ideal to be able to search all of Nietzsche's works simultaneously, but I'd be delighted to be able to search his books one by one. I used to use [Lexido](http://www.lexido.com/https://) for this purpose, but it is no longer being maintained. The search function no longer works.

My memory is pretty good, but locating a specific aphorism among the many thousands Nietzsche wrote can be as time-consuming and frustrating as searching for a needle in a haystack.

What I happen to be looking for at the moment is an aphorism Nietzsche wrote about (his) thoughts/ideas. When they are new/young, they are malicious and wicked and fun, but as they age/mature, they begin to lose their sprightly qualities/luster and run the risk of hardening into truths. Plenty of possible keywords. Do you happen to know where I can find this in Nietzsche's corpus?

Comment: It seems that they just changed the url, http://www.lexido.com/Search_Texts.aspx

Comment: @Conifold Thanks. When I go to Lexido and click on SEARCH TEXTS, I end up at the URL you noted. However, when I enter a word into the search box, all I get are advertisements. Does your experience differ?

Comment: @Conifold A little more information … I can't search, even when I register and sign in. I also sent an email to the system administrator, who emailed me back "Hi, Yes, the text search function no longer works - sorry, the website is no longer being maintained."

Comment: My method: pick a very specific word and look for its German equivalent(s) in the eKGWB http://www.nietzschesource.org/#eKGWB .For the ýoung ideas., just a guess in Political writings ch. Agonistic politics p.69 (googlebooks)

Comment: Surprised to see no one mentioned, both Project Gutenberg & Google Books versions of post-copyright texts are fully searchable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the relevant Nietzsche texts on a Kindle then the search functionality on there works fine, for me anyway. It can search across multiple texts as well as within a text.